# Search and update document on Firebase Cloud function

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to integrate Stripe with Firebase as a backend.
I need to create stripe customer when new user signs up to my app.
for that I wrote 1 cloud function which will execute when new user created by Firebase Auth.
but in that function I'm getting Firebase auth's user.
from that I need to update my collection's document which is created for that user. (I'm storing Auth user's uid in my collection's document).
but somehow Firebase cloud function is not updating it.
Here is my Cloud function for same.

```
// When a user is created, register them with Stripe
exports.createStripeCustomer = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  const customer = await stripe.customers.create({email: user.email});
  return admin.firestore().collection('fl_users').doc(user.uid).set({customer_id: customer.id});
});
```

I don't know what need to update how. Can you please help me to solve my problem?

Comment: Do you see any error in the Cloud Functions console?

Comment: Also note that you need to be on the "Blaze" pricing plan. As a matter of fact, the free "Spark" plan "allows outbound network requests only to Google-owned services".

Comment: @RenaudTarnec no, there no error on console, Yes I'm on blaze plan

Comment: are you positive that there is a value on the customer variable?

Comment: yes. @andresmijares

Comment: would you mind to paste a screenshot of the logs of an execution? a few console logs would be useful, I would also try to await the doc set and then trying to return a dummy promise just to debug, I cannot find any mistake on your implementation